# Is the damage of the attack that triggers Press the Attack also amplified?

Tags: league-of-legends

Press the Attack is a new rune during this preseason's rune changes. It's effect causes enemies to take 12% more damage from all sources if you basic attack them 3 times.

Some champions have abilities that enhance their auto attack damage. For example, Vayne's passive does extra true damage if she attacks the same target three times. Ezreal's Q applies on-hit effects, so it's (kind of) a skill shot basic attack. Nasus' Q does more damage the more stacks he has. Etc. etc.

Does the extra damage from these "enhancements" get amplified by 12% on the third attack, or does that boost only start after Press the Attack has been triggered (fourth attack and onward)?

Comment: I'm not sure *where* the proof is, I forgot, but it's proven that any passive that activates on damage, will not apply on itself, meaning that only the 4th attack would be amplified. I may try to prove it later if I can't find the previous material

Comment: It currently does, however that is getting changed in the next patch. According to designer rick maher [on twitter](https://twitter.com/ricklessabandon/status/932538349226618880) "PtA - 3rd attack no longer gets amp on itself before dmg+proc".

Comment: It is not supposed to proc on 3rd attack, it's supposed to proc after 3 attacks or "different abilities" -> in the case of most mages that puts all their skills on cooldown which is how it's designed. If it  does proc on the 3rd hit it's a bug

Comment: @TJ Press the Attack is explicitly only triggered on basic attacks. You're thinking of Electrocute, which is this season's Thunderlord's equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of patch 7.24 all bonuses apply on and after the 4th hit**

So I just tested this in the practice tool and the 12% bonus damage are applied on the 3rd hit for both the **initial attack and the bonus effect**.

The 12% damage taken increase will be applied **before** the damage.

For testing I used Siphoning strike (about 1.4k stacks) and Sheen on Nasus and I've also tested Kayle's E. Other attacks and effects should behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

An update to Jutschge's answer:

Since [patch 7.24](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-724-notes), Press the Attack no longer applies the damage amplification to the 3rd hit, but rather after the 3rd hit.